# Laravel 5.5 Localization in Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.5

we're trying to route to different languages, but isn't working that well c 
  urrently. We work with language folders.

We have currently:
`example.com/hotelA` (if someone access this it automatically changes the language according to IP).

Now we would like to have direct links for the all languages:

- `example.com/**en**/hotelA/`
- `example.com/**tr**/hotelA/`

We solved the switcher in button of our page like this:

```php
Route::get('language/{locale}', function ($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    Session::put('custlocale',$locale);

    return back();
});
```

But this is only working when some triggers the button. 
So we tried:

```php
Route::get('/{locale}/{slug}/', 'frontEnd\HotelController@showHotel'), function ($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    Session::put('custlocale',$locale);

    return back();
});
```

Isn't working really. So we tried many other things but we couldn't solve it properly. Any idea how to solve this properly? Maybe best practices?

Comment: `{locale}/{slug}` is a bit dangerous because indirectly entire URI text became random. Text like `skdljfjk/asjkdsjd` would also be catched by your route.

Comment: Right thats we are asking the question :)

Answer (score 0):

`App::setLocale($locale)` will only change the locale for the current request, and setting the locale in the session will not change the locale used by Laravel.

If you want to use the locale that has been set in the session, you could add a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) to your website that takes the locale from the session and sets it for the current request using `App::setLocale()`.